# Event Multiple Calculator/Generator? - MatLab

Tags: matlab, events, generator, combinations

This might be an obvious question to some, however I am a beginner coder and would appreciate any links or advice I can get.

I am trying to create a code to generate a matrix with values based on the number of possible occurring events.

I am considering each end-member I have an independent event (this is being applied to a end-member mixing scenario in chemistry). Each of these events can occur 2 different ways (the value can be negative or positive). I am also trying to make this code capable of any number of independent events. I am thinking this matrix will be, ncol = the number of independent events, and nrows = the number of event multiples.

For example: If I have 3 independent events (3 columns in matrix), with 2 possible occurrences each (positive or negative), that means there are 8 event multiples or combinations (8 rows in the matrix).

For each combination (row), I would like to automatically generate the outcomes if I only use "1" to indicate the value is positive and "-1" to indicate the value is negative. The order of the row combinations should not matter.

Unfortunately I am using MatLab R2015a, but I was thinking a similar function to what I'm asking is called "combnk" or "combntns" in MatLab R2016a.

```
% Beginning of code:
  NoIndEvents = 3;   % Number of independent events
  NoOccur     = 2;   % Number of occurrences for each ind. event
  newmatrix = ones(NoOccur^NoIndEvents,NoIndEvents); % Initialize matrix

  % Have no idea how to generate this part...

  % My desired output (no hard coding & easily modified for any
  % number of columns/ ind. events)

  newmatrix = 
       1   1   1
      -1  -1  -1
       1   1  -1
       1  -1   1
      -1   1   1
      -1  -1   1
      -1   1  -1
       1  -1   1
```

Does anyone know of a function I can use for this? I have a feeling this might be super easy and I just can't wrap my brain around the coding aspect of it...

Thank you in advance!
~Sydney

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `nchoosek`, `combnk`, etc. do not consider ordering of the result so they won't produce enough combinations (i.e `[-1 -1 1]` is the same as `[1 -1 -1]`). You could generate all permutations of your input (with each possible value duplicated `NoIndEvents` times). And then use `unique` on the first `NoIndEvents` columns of the result to get all of your permutations.

```
P = perms(repmat([-1 1], NoIndEvents, 1));
out = unique(P(:,1:NoIndEvents), 'rows')

    -1    -1    -1
    -1    -1     1
    -1     1    -1
    -1     1     1
     1    -1    -1
     1    -1     1
     1     1    -1
     1     1     1
```

Comment: Thank you!! I also just found the combinator.m on fileexchange which seems to be useful too!